# Dynamodb connection: strange behaviour

Tags: spring, spring-boot, amazon-dynamodb, razorsql

I have created an Amazon DynamoDB database in a Docker container using this request:

```
curl -X POST http://192.168.99.100:8000/ -H 'accept-encoding: identity' -H 'authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=key/20170515/us-east-1/execute-api/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=accept-encoding;content-length;content-type;host;x-amz-date;x-amz-target, Signature=f2f21c6263ad5380aaa' -H 'cache-control: no-cache' -H 'content-type: application/json' -H 'x-amz-date: 20170515T151032Z' -H 'x-amz-target: DynamoDB_20120810.CreateTable' -d '{"AttributeDefinitions": [{"AttributeName": "userId","AttributeType": "S"}],"TableName": "User","KeySchema": [{"AttributeName": "userId","KeyType": "HASH"}],"ProvisionedThroughput": {"ReadCapacityUnits": 1,"WriteCapacityUnits": 1}}'
```

When I list the tables using a `curl` command like that:

```
curl -X POST http://192.168.99.100:8000/ -H 'authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=key/20170515/us-east-1/execute-api/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=accept-encoding;content-length;content-type;host;x-am z-date;x-amz-target' -H 'cache-control: no-cache' -H 'content-type: application/json' -H 'x-amz-date: 20 170515T151032Z' -H 'x-amz-target: DynamoDB_20120810.ListTables ' -d '{}'
```

All works fine. I get the list of the tables:

```
{"TableNames":["UserTable1","User", "TestTable]}
```

The problem is when I connect to this database using RazorSQL there is no table on it. I have the same problem with my application spring-boot it raise an exception:

```
Cannot do operations on a non-existent table (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400;
```

Would you have any ideas about this strange behaviour ?

this is a screen shot of my connection profile:

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for the table on the correct region in RazorSQL?

Comment: Thanks @notionquest. I  added region in the URL like that but the problem still persist. `http://192.168.99.100:8000/us-east-1`.  I added a screenshot to my question.

Answer (score 2):

When using DynamoDB locally, you should be aware of the following:

- If you use the `-sharedDb` option, DynamoDB creates a single database file named *shared-local-instance.db*. Every program that connects to DynamoDB accesses this file. If you delete the file, you lose any data you have stored in it.
- If you omit `-sharedDb`, the database file is named *myaccesskeyid_region.db*, with the AWS access key ID and region as they appear in your application configuration. If you delete the file, you lose any data you have stored in it.

So, make sure you're passing `-shareDb`.

Those who are using [the official](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/08/use-amazon-dynamodb-local-more-easily-with-the-new-docker-image/) [DynamoDB Local Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/amazon/dynamodb-local/) can do that like this:

```
docker run -p 8000:8000 amazon/dynamodb-local -jar DynamoDBLocal.jar -inMemory -sharedDb
```

The original [`ENTRYPOINT`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint) and [`CMD`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd) used by the image can be seen in `docker inspect amazon/dynamodb-local` output and are:

```
"Entrypoint": [
    "java"
]
"Cmd": [
    "-jar",
    "DynamoDBLocal.jar",
    "-inMemory"
]
```

So we basically copied them and added `-sharedDb`.